# How do I save values from variables?

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json, console

So right now, I'm printing values from my vars to the console, but what I really want to do is somehow save these values in a new array every time the user clicks ".one". Is this even possible?

Here's my code:

```
function addNewTimer() {
  //add a new timer
  $(".one .add").click(function() {
    $('.one').append('<span class="newtimer stoptimer">1000</span><br/>').html();
    $('.one .newtimer:last').prop('Counter', 0).animate({
      Counter: 1000
    }, {
      duration: timerclock, //default 100 mins = 60000000,
      easing: 'linear',
      step: function(now) {
        $(this).text(Math.ceil(now));
      }

    });
    arr1 = {}
    arr1.role = $(".one .positiontitle").text();
    arr1.team = "Account";
    arr1.rate = cost1;
    arr1.time_start = new Date();
    arr1.time_start_perc = Number($(".stoptimer:first").text() / 60);
    console.log(arr1);
    $(".one").append('<span class="role"></span><br/>').html();
    $(".one").append('<span class="team"></span><br/>').html();
    $(".one").append('<span class="rate"></span><br/>').html();
    $(".one").append('<span class="time_start"></span><br/>').html();
    $(".one").append('<span class="time_start_perc"></span><br/>').html();
    $(".one .role:last").append(arr1.role);
    $(".one .team:last").append(arr1.team);
    $(".one .rate:last").append(arr1.rate);
    $(".one .time_start:last").append(arr1.time_start);
    $(".one .time_start_perc:last").append(arr1.time_start_perc);
  });
}
```

Comment: Please post your html so we can create an working example.

Comment: Should your array be persistent when you refresh the page? Do you need that array only in js or also in php (since you added the php tag)

Comment: You just want to add a value to an array? Initialise the array somewhere with `var myArray=[];`, then add `myArray.push(arr1);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send ajax request to store the data.

near console.log(arr1); use following (I suppose you're using jquery):

```
var dataArray=JSON.stringify(arr1);
$.ajax({

   url: '/store.php',
   type: 'POST',
   data: { data: dataArray },
   success: function() {console.log('Data sent to server'); }

});
```

Now your store.php may look like this:

```
<?php

  $data = $_POST;

  var_dump($data); //debug if you want

  //Now you can store in your database.
```

You can also use GET Request if you want but remember to change type in your JS code.

I hope this works for you and you were looking for this. :)

Answer (score 0):

You have following options:

- Save your data locally in the browser using the **localStorage**. This is a quite simple step, but the User could delete this data. Have a look to this link if you want to use the localStorage:
  https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage
- Save your data on an server. Therefor you need a backend which saves the data to an database, file or whatever. You can write an quite simple PHP/NodeJS backend with an API end point to save and one to load the data.
  You can save and load the data from the server using [`jQuery.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

Comment: Thanks for replying! The thing is - I don't just want to keep pushing these values to the same array. I want to create a brand new array every time we click on ".one". Basically, I want to save the values of the exact moment every time the user presses the button, I'm not sure how to go about doing this.

Comment: How do you want to save the values - permanent (for the next time he visits the website) or temporary (to do some stuff with value)? - My problem is that i don't know what you want to do with your values after the click. I think i can help you more if you explain more exact what you want to do.

Comment: okay so I basically want my values to be permanently saved on a separate page.

Comment: Best way would be to use an server backend and an ajax call -Otherwise you could use the localStorage of the browser.